# Unable to load the mojo 'set-version' in the plugin due to an API incompatibility

Tags: java, maven-3, alfresco

I am trying to implement alfresco in my eclipse and I can't get the error message "Maven build error" to go away. I am currently using jdk 7 and jre 7 in eclipse. The full error message can be found in the bottom of this question.

---

```
Execution default-set-version of goal org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:2.0.0:set-version failed: Unable to load the mojo 'set-version' in the plugin 'org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:2.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/alfresco/maven/plugin/VersionMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:2.0.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/alfresco/maven/plugin/alfresco-maven-plugin/2.0.0/alfresco-maven-plugin-2.0.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-containers/2.3.0/guice-bean-containers-2.3.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-inject/2.3.0/guice-bean-inject-2.3.0.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-shim/2.3.0/guice-plexus-shim-2.3.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-reflect/2.3.0/guice-bean-reflect-2.3.0.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-locators/2.3.0/guice-bean-locators-2.3.0.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-binders/2.3.0/guice-bean-binders-2.3.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-scanners/2.3.0/guice-bean-scanners-2.3.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-converters/2.3.0/guice-bean-converters-2.3.0.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-metadata/2.3.0/guice-plexus-metadata-2.3.0.jar
urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-converters/2.3.0/guice-plexus-converters-2.3.0.jar
urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-locators/2.3.0/guice-plexus-locators-2.3.0.jar
urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-binders/2.3.0/guice-plexus-binders-2.3.0.jar
urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-scanners/2.3.0/guice-plexus-scanners-2.3.0.jar
urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-lifecycles/2.3.0/guice-plexus-lifecycles-2.3.0.jar
urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.3/plexus-archiver-2.3.jar
urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.6/plexus-io-2.0.6.jar
urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar
urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/alfresco/alfresco-mmt/5.0.c/alfresco-mmt-5.0.c.jar
urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/alfrescolabs/alfresco-technical-validation/org.alfrescolabs.alfresco-technical-validation/0.4.0/org.alfrescolabs.alfresco-technical-validation-0.4.0.jar
urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar
urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.cli/0.3.1/tools.cli-0.3.1.jar
urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.logging/0.3.0/tools.logging-0.3.0.jar
urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/clojurewerkz/neocons/3.0.0/neocons-3.0.0.jar
urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/cheshire/cheshire/5.3.1/cheshire-5.3.1.jar
urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.1/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile/2.3.1/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.3.1.jar
urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/tigris/tigris/0.1.1/tigris-0.1.1.jar
urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/clj-http/clj-http/0.9.1/clj-http-0.9.1.jar
urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.2/httpclient-4.3.2.jar
urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.2/httpmime-4.3.2.jar
urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/slingshot/slingshot/0.10.3/slingshot-0.10.3.jar
urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/crouton/crouton/0.1.1/crouton-0.1.1.jar
urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.7.1/jsoup-1.7.1.jar
urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/0.8.3/tools.reader-0.8.3.jar
urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/potemkin/potemkin/0.3.4/potemkin-0.3.4.jar
urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/clj-tuple/clj-tuple/0.1.2/clj-tuple-0.1.2.jar
urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/riddley/riddley/0.1.6/riddley-0.1.6.jar
urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/clojurewerkz/support/0.20.0/support-0.20.0.jar
urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar
urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/clojurewerkz/urly/2.0.0-alpha5/urly-2.0.0-alpha5.jar
urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar
urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/me/raynes/conch/0.7.0/conch-0.7.0.jar
urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/flatland/useful/0.10.6/useful-0.10.6.jar
urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.1/tools.macro-0.1.1.jar
urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/jansi-clj/jansi-clj/0.1.0/jansi-clj-0.1.0.jar
urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/io/aviso/pretty/0.1.12/pretty-0.1.12.jar
urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojars/pmonks/depends/0.3.0/depends-0.3.0.jar
urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.json/0.2.4/data.json-0.2.4.jar
urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar
urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-kernel-impl/0.10.6/truevfs-kernel-impl-0.10.6.jar
urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-kernel-spec/0.10.6/truevfs-kernel-spec-0.10.6.jar
urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-cio/2.3.4/truecommons-cio-2.3.4.jar
urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-io/2.3.4/truecommons-io-2.3.4.jar
urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-services/2.3.4/truecommons-services-2.3.4.jar
urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-logging/2.3.4/truecommons-logging-2.3.4.jar
urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.3/scala-library-2.10.3.jar
urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-access/0.10.6/truevfs-access-0.10.6.jar
urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-driver-file/0.10.6/truevfs-driver-file-0.10.6.jar
urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-driver-zip/0.10.6/truevfs-driver-zip-0.10.6.jar
urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-comp-ibm437/0.10.6/truevfs-comp-ibm437-0.10.6.jar
urls[82] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-comp-zipdriver/0.10.6/truevfs-comp-zipdriver-0.10.6.jar
urls[83] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-comp-zip/0.10.6/truevfs-comp-zip-0.10.6.jar
urls[84] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.7/commons-compress-1.7.jar
urls[85] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
urls[86] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truevfs/truevfs-driver-jar/0.10.6/truevfs-driver-jar-0.10.6.jar
urls[87] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-key-disable/2.3.4/truecommons-key-disable-2.3.4.jar
urls[88] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-key-spec/2.3.4/truecommons-key-spec-2.3.4.jar
urls[89] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/java/truecommons/truecommons-shed/2.3.4/truecommons-shed-2.3.4.jar
urls[90] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojars/pmonks/multigrep/0.2.0/multigrep-0.2.0.jar
urls[91] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojars/pmonks/bookmark-writer/0.1.0/bookmark-writer-0.1.0.jar
urls[92] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/docx4j/docx4j/3.0.1/docx4j-3.0.1.jar
urls[93] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-svg11/1.0.2/jaxb-svg11-1.0.2.jar
urls[94] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-xslfo/1.0.1/jaxb-xslfo-1.0.1.jar
urls[95] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-xmldsig-core/1.0.0/jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar
urls[96] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
urls[97] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/1.5/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar
urls[98] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
urls[99] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/1.1/fop-1.1.jar
urls[100] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svg-dom/1.7/batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar
urls[101] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-anim/1.7/batik-anim-1.7.jar
urls[102] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-css/1.7/batik-css-1.7.jar
urls[103] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-dom/1.7/batik-dom-1.7.jar
urls[104] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-parser/1.7/batik-parser-1.7.jar
urls[105] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-util/1.7/batik-util-1.7.jar
urls[106] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-bridge/1.7/batik-bridge-1.7.jar
urls[107] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-script/1.7/batik-script-1.7.jar
urls[108] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-js/1.7/batik-js-1.7.jar
urls[109] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-xml/1.7/batik-xml-1.7.jar
urls[110] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-awt-util/1.7/batik-awt-util-1.7.jar
urls[111] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-gvt/1.7/batik-gvt-1.7.jar
urls[112] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-transcoder/1.7/batik-transcoder-1.7.jar
urls[113] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svggen/1.7/batik-svggen-1.7.jar
urls[114] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-extension/1.7/batik-extension-1.7.jar
urls[115] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-ext/1.7/batik-ext-1.7.jar
urls[116] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.3.1/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar
urls[117] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.3.1/avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar
urls[118] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar
urls[119] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar
urls[120] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/net/arnx/wmf2svg/0.9.0/wmf2svg-0.9.0.jar
urls[121] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-scratchpad/3.8/poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar
urls[122] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi/3.8/poi-3.8.jar
urls[123] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.3/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar
urls[124] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
urls[125] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
urls[126] = file:/C:/Users/abcd-Services/.m2/repository/org/clojars/pmonks/spinner/0.2.0/spinner-0.2.0.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>gov.ocse:workplacesAmp:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]

-----------------------------------------------------
 (org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:2.0.0:set-version:default-set-version:initialize) pom.xml /workplacesAmp  line 12 Maven Build Problem
```

Comment: Yikes, this post is in need of some cleanup / editing - I see that someone has already taken this on for you @vbr. In the future, please use the appropriate formatting when posting code or error messages.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml.

Comment: You need to add more details like which Alfresco SDK version you are using?Because SDK 2.1 is only compatible with JDK 8. Then check you maven version it should be 3.2.5.